# Powershell structur "Wrapping" codeblocks without scope shift

Tags: powershell, scope, structure

As my script is getting pretty long and it will get longer I was wondering if I could wrap around some codeblocks without changeing really the scope or values.

I'm speacking of something like div containers on html or even something like only wrap around "int main (void)" from c languages

```
#Select which option Form

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "CSV Liste"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,195)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,195)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Welche CSV Liste soll geladen werden:"
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$listBox.Height = 150

[void] $listBox.Items.Add("AS400 Computer")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("AS400 Personalstamm")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADComputer")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADBenutzer")

#Formclosed
```

This would be the perfect part of my script to wrap around in something like a div container to get some structur into, but I dont know if there is an option like this without changing scopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with PowerShell ISE, you can use `#region`:

[image]

Now you can collapse each individual region. You an also nest them.

Comment: that will do what i need is there a way to have one or two region inside another bigger one ?

Comment: Yes, you can nest them.